# install tomcat-apache-manager in ubuntu

Tags: java, apache, tomcat7

I have installed tomcat server on my Ubuntu. I have to deploy a `war` file via tomcat manager.

However, I am getting an error 404:

[image: error 404]

Hostname: 87.76.29.180
Port number:8080

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What happens if you deploy your .war file in tomcat/webapps/ directory ?

Comment: I have copied the sample.war file in webapps directory of tomcat.

I can acess 87.76.29.180:8080.

deploying of wars is automatic by default -i have checked my webapps folder for an extracted folder "sample"

but it is not extracted.why the war file is doesn't extracted.please give me solution for this.

Comment: Did you checked after restarting tomcat?

Comment: As user1796222 commented the folder should be extracted if you just stop and start your tomcat server (`sh /tomcatfolder/bind/shutdown.sh` and then `startup.sh`)

Comment: i have restarted my server after that i have checked at this time also my war file is doesn't extracted.

Comment: @stsd ya i have checked this way also.i have stop the server first after have to start the server.now also my war file is doesn't extracted.

Comment: Can you browse the page via port 8080? How you have created the .war file? are you restarting the right tomcat server?

Comment: yes.i have created war file using eclipse.I have export WAR file from the Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse.